# Результат выгрузки из БД в переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли записать результат вывода из БД или из массива POST в переменную, чтобы потом записать в БД MySQL?

Возникла такая задача: на странице есть множество INPUT с разными именами. Их может быть 1, 5, 10 и т.д. заранее неизвестно.
Поступаю так: на странице обработчика строю таблицу и в нее через

```
    <div class="table-responsive">      
        <table class="table table-light table-striped table-hover align-items-center  text-center">

        <tr>
            <th class="col">Текст1</th>
            <th class="col">Текст2</th>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
        echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></td>";
        ?>
        
        </table> 
    </div>
```

вывожу значения всех POST, переданных из формы.

Проблема  заключается в следующем. Необходимо сохранить как HTML результат работы foreach и построенной таблицы со значениями в переменную и записать в MySQL, чтобы потом можно было показать эту таблицу уже со всеми значениями как HTML.
Как сохранить в переменную и записать в БД - знаю, но не могу получить в переменную уже построенную на foreach таблицу, без php внутри.

Если сказать по-другому: необходимо сохранить как HTML указанный выше код, с уже выведенными значением через foreach.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

буферизация вывода в помощь.

```
ob_start(); 
... // генерим разметку
$contents = ob_get_contents();   
ob_end_clean();
```

включаем буферизацию, генерим разметку. получаем содержимое буфера в переменную и очищаем его, выключая буферизацию. Далее с полученным контентом делаем, что хотим

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает как надо!